# Erro ao enviar APK do PhoneGap pro GooglePlay

Tags: android, linux, apache-cordova, google-play

Ao enviar o APK do PhoneGap pro GooglePlay apresenta o seguinte erro:

> ENVIAR NOVO APK PARA PRODUÇÃO
>
> O envio falhou Você fez o upload de um APK depurável. Por razões de
>   segurança, desative a depuração antes de publicá-lo no Google Play.
>   Saiba mais sobre APKs depuráveis.. Você enviou um APK assinado no modo
>   de depuração. Assine seu APK no modo de lançamento. Saiba mais sobre
>   como assinar. Use um nome de pacote diferente.
>   "io.cordova.hellocordova" já existe no Google Play.

Como resolver isso ?

Comment: É como o @Cordovaing respondeu, precisa mandar um APK assinado para lançamento (release). Não sei qual IDE você está utilizando, se for Eclipse os passos demonstrados servem, se for outro, procure a documentação do seu IDE. Você poderia também adicionar tal informação na pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Olá!

Você deve mandar um APK assinado digitalmente com uma binário chamado **"Keystore"**. Como forma de melhor entendimento, é como se você estivesse tentando enviar uma versão de DEBUG em vez de uma de RELEASE.

Para resolver o problema no Eclipse, basta fazer o seguinte:

- 1 - Clique com o botão direito no ícone do projeto;
- 2 - Selecione a opção: **Android Tools > Exporte Signed Application
  Package...**
- 3 - A seguinte tela aparecerá:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- 4 - Selecione a opção Create keystore. Nomeie e atribua uma senha ao
  seu arquivo;
- 5 - Pronto! Agora, sempre que você precisar criar um pacote assinado,
  use o mesmo arquivo que você acabou de criar.

Espero que ajude. :)